# Replace PHP code in HIGHCHARTS code

Tags: php, highcharts

I have `Highcharts` code as below:

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ''+
                this.series.name +': '+ (100 - (this.y)) +' ('+ this.y +'%)';
        }
    },
```

And `PHP` code as below:

```
 $Blue = ((int)$data[6] -(int)$data[7]);
 $Red =  (int)$data[7];
```

I want to replace `(100 - (this.y))` by this 2 variables `$Blue` and `$Red` because in arc y I have 2 numbers for display[Please see the second chart](http://www.unitead.pro/kama/stats/unitead_chart/bar_charts.php). But I do not know how to fix it, anyone know help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hilarudeens` has provided two working solutions for you

Let me add one more to the bunch of options available ;)

I would prefer **(& encourage everyone in doing so too)** to not mix my JS & PHP, always put all your javascript in a js file.

In PHP,
You could use an **[`hidden` `input`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp)** tag as follows

```
<input type="hidden" 
       value="<?php echo 'Some Value'; ?>" 
       id="hiddenValue" />
```

What this would do is add an input tag and allows to add a value to it.

Now in javascript you can read the value from this input and store in your JS variable

```
var hiddenValue=$("#hiddenValue").val();
```

For your code

## PHP

```
<?php
$Blue = ((int)$data[6] -(int)$data[7]);
$Red =  (int)$data[7];
?>
<input type="hidden" 
       value="<?php echo  $Blue; ?>" 
       id="blueValue" />
<input type="hidden" 
       value="<?php echo $Red; ?>" 
       id="redValue" />
```

## JS

```
 var blue = parseInt($("#blueValue").val());
 var red = parseInt($("#redValue").val());
 ...
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ''+
                this.series.name +': '+ (blue - red) +' ('+ this.y +'%)';
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your javascript code in PHP(.php) file, Then you can replace as,

```
<?php
$Blue = 100;
$Red = 200;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("Blue is " + <?php echo $Blue; ?> );
alert("Red is " + <?php echo $Red; ?> );
</script>
```

OR

your javascript and php were exist in different files, Then do as follows

//myphp.php file

```
<?php
$Blue = 100;
$Red = 200;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var blue = <?php echo $Blue; ?>;
var red = <?php echo $Red; ?> ;
</script>
```

//myjs.js file

```
alert("Blue is " + blue);
alert("Red is " + red);
```

And be sure that your javascript code in myphp.php file executed prior to run code in myjs.js file.

Note: This is for your understanding, not exact code.

Answer (score 0):

```
tooltip: {

    formatter: function() {
        return ''+
            this.series.name +': '+ (<?php echo $Blue - $Red ?>) +' ('+ this.y +'%)';
    }
},
```